# shaperenderer rounded corner triangle

Tags: libgdx

I would like to create a triangle shape with rounded corners. I can't use a sprite since the shape will change all the time so shaperenderer seems as a good option. I currently do:

```
     shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(0.2f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    // shapeRenderer.filledTriangle(50f, 50f, 55f, 55f, 60f, 60f);
    shapeRenderer.triangle(0, 0, 5f, 5f, 5f, 4f);

    shapeRenderer.end();
```

which produce something like:

[image]

but I need something like:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: 3 filled circles and polygon instead?

Answer (score 0):

Either use an image that you draw from Photoshop with `Sprite` and `SpriteBatch`, or a **Stencil** to cut out the edges.